# jQuery .click handler not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have jQuery .click(function() event handlers attached to elements that I've selected by ID

example:

```
$('#deletethis').click(function() {
   $(this).hide()
}
```

within my $(document).ready  but this does not work at all with Safari, just nothing happens but it works fine with Chrome, Firefox, and IE. Console reports no javascript errors. Nothing inside the .click handler gets executed at all. Is there a work around for safari to accomplish the same effect?

Comment: Post a complete code sample with a tiny bit of your HTML and the javascript in it.  Because this *should* work and so it's likely you have something else going on.

Comment: I assume you're not missing the end ')' in your code. Otherwise it wouldn't work in the other browsers. Other than that, Safari will have no trouble with this code. Probably a mistake elsewhere is affecting it.

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind, found out it was an issue with only Safari not loading the javascript file, but all other browsers are. Got to figure that out now. . .

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
$('#deletethis').click(function() { $(this).hide(); });
```

Note the extra **;** and **);**

Answer (score 0):

Put a semicolon after hide().

End the click function with a ');' after the function.

Answer (score 0):

Is #deletethis a link? Possibly with href="". If so, the default action on it is to navigate to the url of the page.

You can prevent the default action by calling e.preventDefault() in the click handler.

```
$('#deletethis').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: The "return false;" keeps the event from bubbling up to higher level objects.